# Using the Current Month in a Folder Path in VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, save

When I run this code I get an error message

> "compile error: named argument not found".

```vb
Sub SavetoCurrentMonth()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     
     ' Check for month folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("C:\Users\OsmonBek\Documents\macros test\" & Format(Month(Date), "P00-") & Format(Date, "mmmm"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Users\OsmonBek\Documents\macros test\" & Format(Month(Date), "P00-") & Format(Date, "mmmm")
    End If
     
     ' Save File
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\OsmonBek\Documents\macros test\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsx" _
      , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     
     ' Popup Message
    MsgBox "File Saved As:" & vbNewLine & "C:\Users\OsmonBek\Documents\macros test\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The error was telling you that [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) doesn't have a parameter called `FileFormat`.

I'd use something like this function to return the name of the folder for the current month (creating the folder if it doesn't already exist) like `c:\P2022_04\`.

```
Function getMonthFolderPath() As String
'creates/returns folder name for current month, like: c:\P2022_04\
  Const basePath = "c:\", prefix = "P"
  Dim path As String
  path = basePath & prefix & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm")
  If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path
  getMonthFolderPath = path & "\"
End Function
```

I added the year since (I assume) you don't all April's in the same folder.

---

Here's a variation that will (if needed) create a year folder with a month subfolder, and return that path:

```
Function getMonthFolderPath() As String
  Dim path As String
  path = "c:\"
  path = path & Year(Date)
  If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path
  path = path & "\" & Format(Date, "mm")
  If Dir(path, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir path
  getMonthFolderPath = path & "\"
End Function
```

---

Either variation could be used to save the current file, like this:

```
Sub saveDemo()
'save this workbook like:  C:\2022\04\2022-04-08.xlsm
  Dim fName As String
  fName = getMonthFolderPath & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'ignore overwrite warning
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```